# Populate am4core pie chart from SQL database

Tags: asp.net, charts, amcharts4

I'm trying to populate AmCharts v4 Pie Chart on a ASP.Net webform using jQuery. I'm using SQL server for data storage.

I could fetch the data from server using jQuery list but don't understand how to link with the chart. My jquery code as follows:

```
                function PopulateGteGraph() {
                var data;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Somepage.aspx/GetGteNumbers",
                    data: "{dptName: '" + $("#ddlDatabase").val() + "', stDate: '" + $("#txtLeadFrom").val() + "', endDate: '" + $("#txtLeadTo").val() + "' }",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "text",
                    method: 'POST',
                    success: function (response) {
                        data = JSON.parse(response).d;
                        am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
                        var chart = am4core.create('GtePieGraph', am4charts.PieChart3D);
                        var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries())
                        series.dataFields.valueY = data.CollValue;
                        series.dataFields.categoryX = data.CollName;
                        chart.data = data;
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Requesting all eperts out there to help me out in this situation.

Thanks in advancce.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. What is the specific result of the code you provided (besides that it doesn't work)? Any error message? Does it fail silently?

Comment: The code supposed to populate the graph which it doesn't. Rather i'm getting an error message like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIndex' of undefined" in core.js. My intention is to populate the piechart from SQL database. Please help.

Comment: Hi @Koushik, error messages are very important! Make sure you include that (and, if possible, the specific line in your code where it is thrown) in your post using [edit].